# Прыгает футер и хедер при скролле

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Хедер и футер прибит к верху и низу экрана соответственно. Когда на странице очень много контента, то при скролле вниз хедер и футер прыгают от краев экрана.
Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: сделайте песочницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это из-за того, что браузер не справляется. Но, если

- У вас google chrome, прокрутка не плавная
- У вас позиция элемента генерируется при onscroll

то проблема решается подключением события onmousrwheel.